# Splitting text into several rows in a single cell in Excel using C# and class XLWorkbook

Tags: c#, excel

How to place a text line into several lines in the same cell with C# using the `XLWorkbook` class for Excel file creation? The result should be as shown in the image in cell(2, A):

[image]

Comment: Have a look at left() and right(), also mid() and find() may be useful ie find the dot space “. “ and cut into bits. There are already examples to see on here.

Comment: @SolarMike, no problem to find dot space ".“. The problem is how to set the desired properties of the cell in Excel and put a paragraph mark.
Simply adding characters: /n /r ^13 ^p ChrW(244) - does not bring the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this image shows it works, I will leave it to you to type them in, and test how each part works.

[image]